# Get Value of Hidden Field in Client Side

Tags: asp.net, hidden-field

On a button click on my server side, I assign value to the Hidden Field from a column in my table.

```
Dim dsGetEnquiryDetails = dbl.usp_GetEnquiryRegisterDetails(Val(lblEnquiryRegisterID.Text)).AsQueryable
For Each record In dsGetEnquiryDetails
    HiddenStatusFlag.Value = record.StatusFlag
Next
```

In my client side function I use this, but not getting any value.

```
var StatusFlag = '';
StatusFlag = document.getElementById('<%= HiddenStatusFlag.ClientID%>');
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Often after a "get" like that I'll add a simple `alert(StatusFlag);` to see what the value is.  If it's "null" I know I muffed the command.  If it displays something like "[object HtmlInputElement]" I know I got the control instead of the property I intended.

Comment: The `Visible` property must not be set to `false`. Otherwise js can't see it. It will still be hidden.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

That returns the input. You need the value of the hidden input.

```
StatusFlag = document.getElementById('<%= HiddenStatusFlag.ClientID%>').value;
```

Answer (score 7):

If your hiddenfield used *runat="server"*

Use this code:

```
StatusFlag = document.getElementById('<%= HiddenStatusFlag.ClientID%>').value;
```

else use this code:

```
StatusFlag = document.getElementById("HiddenStatusFlag").value;
```

Comment: Hi Ramesh, thanks :) I have fixed this issue using @NunesPascal's suggestion.

Comment: @Aishvarya Okay fine . Yaar answer'a irunthaa enna ,work mudinja serithaan !!! do well  mam !Cheers

Comment: Mikka Nandri @Ramesh ji :)

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that it's not `null` you don't use the hiddenfield's `value` proprty:

```
var statusFlag = '';
var hiddenStatusFlag = document.getElementById('<%= HiddenStatusFlag.ClientID%>');
if(hiddenStatusFlag != null)
{
    statusFlag = hiddenStatusFlag.value;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

in jquery:

```
var hiddenValue = $('#hiddenFieldID').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
alert(document.getElementById("<%= Hiddenfield1.ClientID %>").value);
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<asp:hiddenfield ID="Hiddenfield1" runat="server" value="Hussain Testing"></asp:hiddenfield>
</div>
<body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

in javascript:

```
var SomeVar = document.getElementById('HiddenField_ID').value;
StatusFlag = SomeVar;
```